# Best Practice for IEnumerable in event arguments

Tags: c#, .net, events, mono, eventargs

I have a DLL including a class for managing audio and midi ports and connections. Whenever ports are registered or deregistered or connections are formed or released, this class fires an event, like `ConnectionChanged` with custom event arguments including properties `Enum ChangeType` and `IEnumerable<Connection> ChangedConnections`

Now my question is: Should I really just send the changed connections or change the property of the event args to `Connections` and send an IEnumerable containing all active connections?

Comment: in the typical case, would the consumer reset *all* their connections, or would they only want to know about the *changed* connections - your answer to this probably answers the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the event is called "ConnectionChanged", you should include the connections that apply to that event in your event arguments. Make all active connections accessible using a member on your class.

When firing the event. You send the actual object that raised the event in the member Sender. So if someone is actually interested in all active connections, it can be obtained through the Sender object.

Comment: OK, this is the way I am already doing it. As you got so many upvotes, it seems to go with the principle of least astonishment.